# Advice / Solution for printing docs from links

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I've got a a simple database setup with a parent child relationship.
Imagine one expense report can have many line items associated with it.
Now inside of this line items table I have a column that stores the link / path
of an attachment on our local storage server.  Some example values could be:

```
\\myserver\attachments\1.pdf
\\myserver\attachments\2.jpg
\\myserver\attachments\someDoc.docx
```

Basically the attachment could be a pdf, a word doc, an image or maybe an xls (excel) file.
Right now I have an asp.net UI that displays the URL's in a hyperlink.  clicking the hyperlink opens the files.  But my end user would like something a bit more easier to maybe print all the attachments at the click of a button?

Is that possible to do this in asp.net?  It's no issue to pull all the line item attachments for each expense report from the database but Im looking for ideas on how to either diplay them all at once or allow printing them all at once.

Any advise or possible solution would be very helpful....

Answer (score 0):

The idea that i can think of is a little bit complex and require a lot of code to do

First you have can create an http handler that reads the links from the database and convert each attachment link to an html printable version of it that can be printed.

Answer (score 0):

ya its possible,

if you have, say, an HP printer that's on the network, you can connect directly to the IP address and appropriate port from the web server, and issue PCL 5 commands directly to the printer. Again, this will only work in very limited cases, but it is possible.